# Why are there hole-less as well as holed sanding discs?

Tags: sanding, random-orbit-sander

The 3M Cubitron 775L is sold in two varieties - with and without holes. The size, price, and grain being the same, why would anybody want a hole-less sanding disc?

These discs are specifically designed for random orbit sanders and not rotary tools.

An ode to the spiral-shaped hole pattern can be found in the description of both products.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are aware that you can use those round papers on other tools as well, not just random orbit sanders?

Comment: I suspect it's for the same reason that other papers are sold hole-less, to cover as many bases as possible. These days that includes people who want to use them by hand (which has become quite a thing in recent years). A reason from the past that may or may not be still relevant is that it allowed custom hole patterns to be stamped in, to suit extraction patterns for older or more unusual sanders. Also worth noting is that Cubitron II is sold in a *third* pattern as well, Xtract, with that sort of open chevron pattern that has even less abrasive on the surface (yet appears to sand faster!)

Comment: One of my RO sanders (an older Porter Cable) has no dust extraction through the pad, so solid disks are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many (most?) abrasive discs are sold in both unperforated and holed versions, see [1](https://www.mafergasa.com/pdf/lixas-dronco.pdf) (PDF), [2a](https://www.biltema.dk/en-dk/tools/sanding/sandpaper/sanding-disc-125-mm-8-holes-25-pack-2000051631) and [2b](https://www.biltema.no/en-no/tools/sanding/sandpaper/sanding-disc-125-mm-unholed-5-pack-2000051629).

The holes are obviously for dust extraction, but not everything these can be fitted to actually has any dust extraction (including the pads sold for [chucking up in drills](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1f97a9e8-e672-433a-a094-e27bd0e2ad0a.85867121bef5e24f59b498c83a6a55fd.jpeg?odnHeight=768&odnWidth=768&odnBg=FFFFFF) and for [mounting to angle grinders](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcRugyP4CzBq2tf4aoJO7ZDpiy_jPGXlE_fBqC0EEpk7W-H3NMCItrXiZgmIFZanNjahsamKLvaPbGoD58ETfQWISxybw-OSQzNGZBugkBN6pkdAIEBZk4cr&usqp=CAE)) so it makes sense for those to use unperforated discs. In addition to the holes serving no purpose for any application that doesn't have through-the-pad dust extraction, in straight orbital sanding there's more potential for any edge of the sandpaper to catch and tear, especially when working on or near edges and corners of hard materials such as metals and stone.

**Note:** Cubitron II is unusual in that there are actually *three* disk types you can buy, the third being Xtract which is mesh based.

[image: Cubitron II Xtract]